# How do I write this in code behind: <Button Command="{prism:NavigateTo 'path/to/navigate'}" />

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, infragistics

I have a common Page class which the rest of my app pages inherit from.

I'm writing the buttons in code but I'd like to replicate the way prims does it as it more predictable/readable for a beginner. e.g.

This is current method. How do I change the Command property below to  do  what the button code does i.e

```
var im_Logo = new ImageButton
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            Source = "blalogo",
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            Command = new   Command(GoHome)// This works but other pages are not so  easy. 
        };  

void GoHome(object obj)
    {
        Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
      
    }
```

Plus I'm just curious how you write  `Command="{prism:NavigateTo 'path/to/navigate'}"`  in code.

If I could attach a Viewmodel to  this 'code' page, it would also solve the problem as the Viewmodels I have have all the Prism stuff built in.(Supplied by infragistics)

Edit Update: I'm adding full class of page I'm creating in code. I thought writing a common class for multiple pages to use would be simple but I'm stumped.
My error on these fails are when clicking on the **Search** button which I'll concentrate on for now is.

```
11-06 16:28:54.988 D/Mono    (30123): Loading reference 0 of System.Drawing.Common.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
11-06 16:28:54.988 D/Mono    (30123): Assembly Ref addref System.Drawing.Common[0xc7e18f60] -> mscorlib[0xe5c08580]: 70
Loaded assembly: System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
11-06 16:28:55.040 D/EGL_emulation(30123): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc9270ce0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc8d25b10)
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'




   using iBasisAppV1.ViewModels;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Prism.Navigation.Xaml;
using Syncfusion.XForms.BadgeView;
using Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
 

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace iBasisAppV1.Views.Templates
{
    public class CommonToolbarPage : ContentPage
    {
        


        public CommonToolbarPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            ShowDefaultTitle();
          //this.BindingContext=  new CommonToolbarPageViewModel(navigationService);

        }


        private void ShowDefaultTitle()
        {
            var im_Logo = new ImageButton
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(0),
                Padding = new Thickness(0),
                Source = "boilerparts",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                Command = new NavigateToExtension { Name = $"/Home" }
                //Command = new   Command(GoHome)
            };


            var b_search = new SfButton
            {
               HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                FontSize = 26,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                Margin = new Thickness(0),
                Padding = new Thickness(0),
                FontFamily = "UIFontIcons",
                Text = (String)Application.Current.Resources["Search"],
                //Command = new NavigateToExtension { Name = "../Search" } //Not  Work
                //Command = new NavigateToExtension { Name = "Search" } //Not  Work
                //Command = new NavigateToExtension { Name = $"{nameof(Search)}" } //Not  Work
               // Command = new NavigateToExtension { Name = $"../{nameof(Search)}" } //Not  Work
                //Command = new Command(ShowSearch)// Works
            };

            var boxView = new BoxView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0),
            };

            SfButton sfButton = new SfButton
            {
                CornerRadius = 4,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                VerticalOptions= LayoutOptions.Center,
                Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["IconButtonStyle"],
                Text = (String)Application.Current.Resources["Cart"],
                FontFamily = "UIFontIcons",
                TextColor = Color.White,
               
               // Command = new Command(GoCart)
            };


            var imSfBadgeView = new SfBadgeView
            {
                BadgeText = "4",
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0),
                Padding = new Thickness(0),
                WidthRequest = 40,
                Content = sfButton,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                BadgeSettings = new BadgeSetting
                {
                    BackgroundColor=  (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PrimaryColor"],
                    BadgeType = BadgeType.None,
                    FontSize = 10,
                    Stroke = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Gray-White"],
                    StrokeWidth = 1,
                    Offset = new Point(-10, 10)
                }
            };

            var layout = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["HeaderColor"]
            };

            var Endlayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
              
            };

            if (this.GetType().Name.ToLower() != "search")
                Endlayout.Children.Add(b_search);
            Endlayout.Children.Add(imSfBadgeView);
           
            layout.Children.Add(im_Logo);
            layout.Children.Add(Endlayout);

            NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, layout);
        }

        private void ShowSearch(object obj)
        {

            Navigation.PushAsync(new Search());

        }

      

       

         private void cancel(object obj)
        {
            ShowDefaultTitle();
        }

        void GoCart(object obj)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Home());
        }

        void GoHome(object obj)
        {
            Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            // Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Home()));
            //NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/ViewA");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/ViewA");` in prism or you want a Xamarin.forms solution without using Prism.

Comment: Ok so  your saying Prism is XAML only and if I write code behind I have to use pushAsync etc.

I was hoping for something like this that I can do  in the ViewModel.
 await _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"/MasterDetail");

However my Custompage class has no access to  the _navigationService as its injected into  the ViewModel but I've no idea how to  get access to  it in Custompage  class.

Comment: Can you access the ViewModel by page's bindingContext?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact match, here we go...

```
var im_Logo = new ImageButton
{
    Margin = new Thickness(0),
    Padding = new Thickness(0),
    Source = "blalogo",
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    Command = new NavigateToExtension {Name = "/path/to/navigate"}
};

void GoHome(object obj)
{
    Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
}
```

And you will need the following import:

```
using Prism.Navigation.Xaml;
```

Long story short, Prism use this class to create a command which can use INavigationService accessing the container in Application.Current. If you check the source code in Github you will see how all the magic happens.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Navigation/Xaml/NavigateToExtension.cs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in ViewModel, then you need a `INavigationService`.
Then you can use it like:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(YourView));
```

So like

```
Command = new Command(async () => await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("YourView"));
```

NavigateAsync uses URI parameters, you can use `../` and `../YourView`.
I like the nameof() method eg. `await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"../{nameof(YourView)}"));`